# How to make a new column in a json file with binarization in python+numpy/pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a JSON file with multiple columns, and one of the columns is a list of diagnoses. I want to make a column based on that column with only the information I need. for example, if I have a column that goes

```
Pneumonia
Cancer
Nodules
Nodules | Cancer
Cancer
Nodules
Pneumonia | Nodules
```

I would like to get a column that filters out only Cancer:

```
Not Cancer
Cancer
Not Cancer
Cancer
Not cancer
Not cancer
```

going from this, using the same method, I would make another column that is binary eg "1" for cancer, "0" for not cancer.

after importing the Json file d, I have:

```
d['Pneumonia']=d['Finding Labels']
for i in d['Finding Labels']:
    #i=i.split("|")
    if 'Pneumonia' in i:
        d['Pneumonia'].replace(i,1)
    else:
        d['Pneumonia'].replace(i,0)
d.head()
```

The output doesn't seem to be replacing the values. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `explode` with `str.contains`

```
s=df['diagnoses'].str.split(' | ').explode()

s=s[s.str.contains('cancer',case=False)]
```

If need assign it back

```
df['New']=s
```